# Java: Actualizar datos de un archivo CSV

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

Estoy intentando modificar los datos de un file CSV desde Java.

En mi `file CSV` tengo salvados los siguientes datos :

```
"Nombre","Apellido","Intereses","Descripcion"
jose,guerra,algo,algo
pedro,perez,algo,algo
manuel,aguirre,algo,algo
```

Clase `Persona`:

```
public class Persona {

        String Nombre;
        String Apellido;
        String Intereses;
        String Descripcion;

        public Persona(String Nombre,String Apellido,String Intereses,String Descripcion)
        {        
                this.Nombre = Nombre;
                this.Apellido= Apellido;
                this.Intereses = Intereses;
                this.Descripcion = Descripcion;

        }

        //respectivos métodos get y set 

        public void setNome(String nombre){
            this.Nombre = nombre;

        }
    }
```

y otra clase `métodos`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import com.opencsv.*;

import java.io.File;

public class métodos {

    static ArrayList<Persona> personas = new ArrayList<Persona>();
    static String directory = "C:\\Users\\BryanPC\\Desktop\\personas.txt";

    public métodos() {

    }
    // escribe los datos salvados en el ArrayList Personas (hay un error se
    // imprimen 4 comillas de mas)

    public static void escribeCSV() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        ArrayList<String[]> datos = personasToArrayListOfString();

        CSVWriter csvOutput = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(directory, true), ',', '"', "\r\n");

        csvOutput.writeAll(datos, false);
        csvOutput.close();

    }

    // lee los datos del CSV y los salva en el ArrayList Personas
    public static void leeCSV() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        File file = new File(directory);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        input.next();

        while (input.hasNext()) {

            String s = input.next();
            String[] data = s.split(",");
            Persona p = arrayOfStringsToPersona(data);

            personas.add(p);
        }

    }

    // cambia el nombre de la primera persona salvada en el ArrayList Personas
    // por Juan
    public static void modificaCSV() {

        for (Persona p : personas) {

            p.setNome("juan");
            break;
        }

    }

    // transforma un objeto de tipo Persona a un ArrayList<String[]> para
    // poder imprimirlo

    public static ArrayList<String[]> personasToArrayListOfString() {

        ArrayList<String[]> datos = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        for (Persona p : personas) {

            String[] s = new String[10];

            String nombre = p.getNombre();
            String apellido = p.getApellido();
            String intereses = p.geIntereses();
            String descripcion = p.getDescripcion();

            s[0] = nombre;
            s[1] = apellido;
            s[2] = intereses;
            s[3] = descripcion;

            datos.add(s);
        }
        return datos;

    }
    // transforma un objeto de tipo String[] a uno de tipo Persona para asi
    // poder añadirlo al ArrayList Personas

    public static Persona arrayOfStringsToPersona(String[] a) {

        String nombre = a[0];
        String apellido = a[1];
        String intereses = a[2];
        String descripcion = a[3];

        Persona p = new Persona(nombre, apellido, intereses, descripcion);

        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        leeCSV();
        // borra o sobreescribe el csv con nuevo nombre "juan"
        modificaCSV();
        metodoFaltante();
        escribeCSV();

    }

}
```

Supongo  vez usado el metodo leeCSV tendra que crear otro método que borre los datos en el file CSV .

O sobreescribir todo lo que esta escrito en el file CSV .

Comment: Para el proceso de archivos CSV, ampliamente te recomiendo que utilices una biblioteca especializada (como [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)), ya que el formato, pese a su aparente simplicidad, puede presentar complicaciones inesperadas (lo sé por propia experiencia)

Comment: Bueno esque estuve saltando de libreria en libreria y simplemente estos metodos fueron los que me funcionaron.

Comment: Hay varias librerías para proceso de CSV (la de Apache me parece bastante buena), y todas tienen sus pros y contras en lo que se refiere a facilidad de uso... pero sí te puedo decir que tratar de implementar la lectura y escritura de archivos CSV a mano puede ser un verdadero dolor de cabeza (cosas que me han pasado: me faltan o me sobran columnas en una fila, se me pasó ponerle comillas al texto, formatos de número... mil cosas pueden salir mal). Por eso creo que es mejor usar una librería ya hecha y probada

Comment: Si que lo es , yo uso para la escritura la libreria OpenCSV pero no pude usarla para la lectura en cambió tuve que usar Scanner.

Comment: Bueno parece que ya lo logre cambiando el segundo parámetro del FileWriter(directory, true) a false .

Comment: @BryanRomero si deseas sobreescribir los datos y no realizar un append debes como comentas tener el segundo parámetro como "false".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es agregar datos al archivo (adjuntar) es correcto lo que realizas:

```
new FileWriter(directory, true)
```

Lo que deseas es borrar los datos y escribir nuevos:

```
new FileWriter(directory, false)
```

Revisa la documentación:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

> **public FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)**
>
> append true, los datos se escriben en el final del archivo.
>
> append false, los datos se escriben en el
> archivo.